# revert back to initial view Fullcalendar React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I have this:

```
<FullCalendar
   initialView="timeGridWeek"
   allDaySlot={false}
   navLinks={true}
   weekends={false} />
```

the problem is, when I click on a date, let's say July 14th, it goes into the date view, which is perfect. But then, I cannot change back into the initialView of `timeGridWeek` . How can I do this?

Comment: Add some buttons to the header so people can navigate between the views and different dates: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/headerToolbar